# Swing testing with AssertJ not working in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, assertj

I want to test a Swing app written with Intellij IDEA. I have been able to setup the initial example, but when trying to execute the example text, I get this message:

```
Unable to find component using matcher org.assertj.swing.core.NameMatcher[name='txtFirstName'
```

Taking a detailed look to the swing component hierarchy reported, I have noticed that every field has the 'name' property set to null, so I figured out that this is the origin the error. The problem is that, in the IntelliJ IDEA swing visual editor, the property 'fieldName' is correctly set, so I don't know how to solve it.

```
Component hierarchy:
javax.swing.JFrame[name='frame0', title='VT Institute', enabled=true, visible=true, showing=true]
  javax.swing.JRootPane[]
    javax.swing.JPanel[name='null.glassPane']
    javax.swing.JLayeredPane[]
      javax.swing.JPanel[name=null]
        javax.swing.JTabbedPane[name=null, selectedTabIndex=0, selectedTabTitle='Students', tabCount=5, tabTitles=["Students", "Courses", "Enrollments", "Reports", "Utilities"], enabled=true, visible=true, showing=true
          javax.swing.JPanel[name=null]
            javax.swing.JTextField[name=null, text='', enabled=true, visible=true, showing=true]
            javax.swing.JTextField[name=null, text='', enabled=true, visible=true, showing=true]
            javax.swing.JTextField[name=null, text='', enabled=true, visible=true, showing=true]
            javax.swing.JTextField[name=null, text='', enabled=true, visible=true, showing=true]
            javax.swing.JTextField[name=null, text='', enabled=true, visible=true, showing=true]
```

I have checked similar issues in stack overflow, but all of them are related to non-visible fields.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialise the name property yourself. It's because there isn't a constructor that may specifically ask you to provide the component name in addition to the caption (in case of JButton) or initial text for JTextField.

AssertJ requires that we must specify the component name for the Component Lookup. AssertJ [examples](https://github.com/assertj/assertj-examples/blob/main/assertj-swing-aut/src/main/java/org/assertj/swing/aut/getting_started/SimpleCopyApplication.java) uses a static method to achieve this important step.

Below is the TextFieldUtil class implementation [here](https://github.com/assertj/assertj-examples/blob/main/assertj-swing-aut/src/main/java/org/assertj/swing/aut/util/swing/TextFieldUtil.java) by AssertJ:

```
public class TextFieldUtil {

  public static JTextField newTextField(String name) {

    JTextField field = new JTextField(20);
    field.setName(name);
    return field;
 }
}
```